# Why is the submanifold a Nullset?

Tags: manifolds, submanifold

I tried to explain myself why a sumbanifold of the dimension $k<n$ is a Nullset in $\mathbb{R}^n$. May this be explained by the fact, that the submanifold is locally coverable by the pictures of Nullsets under a diffeomorphism?

Comment: Yes, this makes the whole submanifold a countable union of nullsets

Comment: But how can I give an argument that it is countable?

Comment: Because separable metric spaces (like $\Bbb R^n$ or any subspace thereof) are [Lindelöf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindelöf_space), meaning any covering of open sets has a countable subcover. So if you have a diffeomorphism on an open neighborhood around each point, then a countable number of those will cover the manifold.